# Add local users to a site collection

Tags: 2010, configuration, login, classic-mode-auth

What do I have to do, to add local users to a site collection?
The web application is running with classic mode authentication.

Active Diretory users do not have any problem to logon.
But local users aren't shown in the people picker and if I add them without picker, I cannot login with that added local user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, if your SharePoint server is in a domain, you can only use Active Directory users. But if that server is a Domain Controller, you can use local users aswell.
Unfortunately the last version of SharePoint you could install on a domain controller was SharePoint 2010.
But even if it is possible, to install some version of SharePoint on a domain controller, it's a really bad idea to do that in production.